# Manipulating limits with denominator approaching 0

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

For example, for an arbitrary function $f$, let's say the derivative at $g(p)$ exists, and $g(p) \ne 0$, can we reduce the following limit as follows:

$\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(h)}{h \cdot g(p+h) \cdot  g(p)} = \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(h)}{h \cdot g^2(p)}$?

My guess is that we cannot, because $\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{1}{h}$ is not finite, but unfortunately I don't know how to formalize/rationalize that.

However, if we say that $f(h) = g(p+h) - g(p)$, then we should be able to do the following (because $g$ is differentiable at $p$):

$$
\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{g(p+h) - g(p)}{h \cdot g(p+h) \cdot  g(p)} = \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{g(p+h) - g(p)}{h} \cdot \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{1}{g(p+h) \cdot g(p)} = \frac{g'(p)}{g^2(p)}
$$

Here the rationale for the first limit is that $g'(p)$ exists and for the second one is that $g$ is continuous (because the limit exists).